# How to get SQLite to request a SQLITE_LOCK_PENDING lock from VFS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, apsw

I'm making a VFS for SQLite in Python using APSW, and specifically one that stores the database in memory: https://github.com/michalc/sqlite-memory-vfs

I want to test its locking logic, but so far, I haven't observed SQLite requesting the SQLITE_LOCK_PENDING lock type for a file. This lock is mentioned at https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/io_methods.html among other places.

How can I make SQLite request the SQLITE_LOCK_PENDING lock type, so I can get confidence that the VFS works when this happens in the real world, outside of tests?

Comment: Judging by the (almost) [only reference](https://github.com/sqlite/sqlite/blob/e24cd27c39de2e6aade490042248af1bc67dfe19/ext/async/sqlite3async.c#L877) in the source code, `LOCK_PENDING` is only used in the asyc-backend, which [is unmaintained and deprecated](https://www.sqlite.org/asyncvfs.html).